# Running .bat file that launches .jar as administrator

Tags: java, windows, h2

So I am trying to set up an H2 database server. So I took the installer from their website ,
 after getting the Path for windows fixed. If I run my bat as typical user the server launches , but when I try to connect it crushes because , writing a lock needs admin rights. So if I try run it as admin , I get ERROR: Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.Console

Comment: Sounds like a classpath problem.  Can you paste the contents of the .bat file?  Or at least just the parts that run the `java` command?

Comment: I edited the original bat by only adding a parameter.

Comment: @user1633277 Could you paste the contents of the .bat file anyway please? Also, could you paste all messages you get (including stack trace if there is any)?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like either

- a classpath problem, if you are including the jar in your own application
  or
- a Windows ACL problem i.e. you're trying to access a part of the filesystem that your user cannot write to.

  or
- both of the above